# Isomorphic subgroups such that the quotient is isomorphic.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, infinite-groups

Does there exists an infinite group $G$ which admits a normal subgroup $H$ such that $G,H,G/H$ are all isomorphic groups?

If I don't remember badly, some time ago I read that the additive group of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. Is this true? If it is, then the answer to my question is affirmative considering $G=\mathbb{R}^2$ and as $H$ we can take the $x$-axis. Is this fact true (and why)?

I have other related questions: does such an example can be of countable cardinality? Does there exist an example in which every element is of finite order (or just there are some of them different from the unit)? Are there such examples in non-abelian groups?

Comment: Yes, your example works as $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are isomorphic as vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$ (same cardinality) and thus also as abelian groups. This means that you can choose $H$ to be one of the coordinate axes in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as you said.

Comment: The isomorphism is true with axiom of choice, but they don't need to be isomorphic in ZF. You can consider free group of countable rank though (kill a countable cocountable free generating set)

Comment: A simpler example would for example be $G = \mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ and $H = \mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: For a countable example, take $G=\mathbb{Z}^{(\mathbb{Z})}$, the direct sum, and $H=\mathbb{Z}^{(\mathbb{N})}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There even exist nontrivial finitely generated groups $G$ isomorphic to $G\times G$, hence, taking the normal subgroup $H=G\times 1$ in $G\times G\cong G$, we obtain an isomorphism 
$G\cong G/N$. See

J. Jones, Direct products and the Hopf property, J. Austral. Math. Soc. 17 (1974), 174-196.

Such groups $G$ are necessarily nonabelian. I am not sure about finitely generated torsion groups, but, most likely, they exist as well.

It is unknown if there are nontrivial finitely presented groups $G$ isomorphic to $G\times G$; see

R. Hirshon, Misbehaved direct products. Expo. Math. 20 (2002), no. 4, 365–374.

Comment: Very interesting!

Answer (score 3):

Under pointwise addition the family of functions $\Bbb F_2^{X}$ from any set $X$ to the finite field $\Bbb F_2$ of two elements is an abelian group all of whose non-trivial elements have finite order 2.

Let $X=\Bbb N$ and let $2\Bbb N, 2\Bbb N+1$ be the set of even/odd positive integers respectively. Let $H$ be the $\Bbb F_2^{\Bbb N}$ subgroup of functions which vanish on $2\Bbb N+1$. Clearly, $$H\approx\Bbb F_2^{2\Bbb N}\approx\Bbb F_2^{2\Bbb N + 1}\approx\frac{\Bbb F_2^{\Bbb N}}{H}$$ and because $\Bbb N,2\Bbb N$ have the same cardinality we also have
$$\Bbb F_2^{\Bbb N}\approx\Bbb F_2^{2\Bbb N}$$

Here, we can replace $\Bbb N$ with any set $X$ and replace $2\Bbb N, 2\Bbb N+1$, respectively, with any two subsets of $X$ that partition $X$ and have the same cardinality as $X$.

Comment: but isn't the question about finitely presented groups? in particular finitely generated?

Comment: @Marco. I believe the question is about infinite groups, their normal subgroups, the quotient between the two and when all three are isomorphic. It is not explicitly assumed that any of these groups must be finitely presented. The question then turned to the example of $\Bbb R$,$\Bbb R^2$ with well posted answers/comments here interestingly dependent on the axiom of choice (ThorWittich, Paul Plummer).  After which I believe Kohan answered both the countably infinite and non-abelian case asked for. My post then answered the torsion group case asked for.

Answer (score 2):

Take $G=\mathbb{Z}^{\infty}\times\mathbb{Z}^{\infty}$.